# What is the time-frame of the 1st season of Daredevil?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

I just finished the first season of Daredevil on Netflix and one thing just stood out to me, that I cannot figure out.

What is the time-frame by which this entire season takes place?

In the first episodes Karen is hired on to the firm and Matt and Foggy barely know her. What feels like days later (weeks at the most) mid-late season she acts like she's emotionally involved with the main cast members. She is devastated by their feuding and what have you but that seems like a really extreme reaction to people you barely know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's considered present day ... if the model of vehicles is of any importance, the Suburban Wilson uses to smash the head clean off of the Russian (S1E3?) is of a newer vintage (could even be current model year).

Comment: @Paulster2 I think the OP is referring to time *span* rather than time *period*.

Comment: @DA. - Well, that would just make *tooooo* much sense. Thanks for the clarification. I'm sure it covers some amount of time ... I mean, Matt gets beat up so often, it does take some time to heal, lol. I don't think he's vying for Wolverine's job here ;-)

Comment: Have you tried imagining that each episode either takes place over the course of a week or a week apart? That's how many of the shows that are actually aired work... Netflix is unusual because they're released in one chunk.

Comment: Well, as to your Karen argument. You have to consider that she doesn't know anyone else in the city and makes friends with them, especially Foggy, very fast. So indeed she is struck when that small comfortable family she has become part of seems to crumble and you also have to consider that at the time when Foggy and Matt have their feud she also has to cope with a very intense trauma in parallel (the kidnapping by and shooting of Fisk's assistant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The show seems to be purposefully vague about the timeline of the events in the series, though it's clearly established to be set at some time after the events of "The Avengers" and either before or during the events of "The Avengers: Age Of Ultron".

Despite the flashbacks that span Matt's childhood and his and Foggy's time at their old job and college, the show does seem to clearly be focused on a span of only a few months. The first episode seems to take place during the Spring/Summer and then at the funeral in the finale it seems to be late Fall / early Winter.

After Matt meets Claire, there is also an episode where it's been clear that he's gone to see her many times over the course of a couple weeks, especially because he only goes out at night.

It also seems intentional because they never show a headstone at the funeral, the newspapers don't have dates on them, and no one in the finale seems to discuss how long it has been. At least partly from watching the series, it seems like this is to let it remain open-ended in context with the rest of the "Marvel Cinematic Universe", as there are several other concurrently airing shows and movies.

The only other possible source of the timeline would be the plans of the cabal with Wilson Fisk and the other gang leaders, but they also seem to have a vague series of events. Most episodes either occur over the course of 1 to 3 days (based on the nights Matt goes out), or they start days or weeks after their preceding episode. But, it's very clearly that everything happens as soon as possible, because of Matt, Wilson, and Karen's motivations/plans.

Without any specific connections to the other Marvel shows/movies mentioned beyond the first episode, it might take until the second season to truly nail-down the timeline of this first season.

Comment: They mention a handful of times that it's been roughly two years since rebuilding efforts in New York after 'The Incident' (first Avengers movie). So the season takes place in 2014.